# External monitor flashing random colors - Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, external-monitor

I just installed Kubuntu (19.10) on my notebook and now my external monitor just won't work. It flashes random colors when connected.

I tried changing the resolution, refresh rate, output mode etc., but nothing works.

I'm connecting through VGA. Also, the same monitor works fine on Windows (dual boot), so the monitor itself isn't faulty, neither is the laptop.

[Here's what happens when I connect it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvOvV.jpg).

**@Edit __________**

Here's the `xrandr` output as mentioned by Asensi:

```
VGA-1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 inverted (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Now the monitor displays a solid white, instead of [these weird coloured flashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvOvV.jpg) like before.

Comment: In case it's helpful, you could add the result of the execution of `xrandr`.